# Import CSV file into Cosmos DB Table Api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to bulk import says 100 records into Cosmos DB.

I found [dt.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-import), that doesn't help. it throws error when importing csv into cosmos db with table api.

I'm not able to find any reliable way to automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The command-line Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration tool (dt.exe) can be
>   used to import your existing Azure Table storage data to a Table API
>   GA account, or migrate data from a Table API (preview) account into a
>   Table API GA account. Other sources are not currently supported. The
>   UI based Data Migration tool (dtui.exe) is not currently supported for
>   Table API accounts.

According to the above [official statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-import#data-migration-tool), it seems that other sources(e.g `csv` file) are not supported to be migrated into Azure Table API account. You could adopt a workaround: Read csv file in the program then import data into Azure Table Storage.

Please refer to the sample python code which I did in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919195/table-storage-sdk/48923417#48923417).

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity
import csv
import sys
import codecs

table_service = TableService(connection_string='***')

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
filename = "E:/jay.csv"

with codecs.open(filename, 'rb', encoding="utf-8") as f_input:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input)
    for row in csv_reader:
        task = Entity()
        task.PartitionKey = row[0]
        task.RowKey = row[1]
        task.description = row[2]
        task.priority = EntityProperty(EdmType.INT32, row[3])
        task.logtime = EntityProperty(EdmType.DATETIME, row[4])
        table_service.insert_entity('tasktable', task)
```

Or you could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Hope it helps you.

---

Just for minor update：

If you use `python 3.1`, there is no need for `reload(sys)` and `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` with `'r' filename = r"E:/jay.csv"`

Comment: @SathishNaga Ok,waiting for your reply.

Comment: thanks, that worked, minor update to script for python 3
1, no need for `reload(sys) and sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`
2, prefix the file path with 'r' `filename = r"E:/jay.csv"}`

Comment: @SathishNaga Thank you for your minor update. I already add it in my answer.